# Overload resolution for operator functions

Tags: c++

Why does this code not compile ?  I would have expected that the built-in unary operator& would have been selected, such that the ambiguity between the two binary operator& should not matter.  If you comment out one of the binary operator&, the code compiles (with gcc 11.2) and the built-in unary operator& is selected.

```
struct A
{ int operator&(int) const { return 1; }
};

struct B
{ int operator&(int) const { return 2; }
};

struct C : A, B
{};

C* test(C& c)
{ return &c; } //error: request for member 'operator&' is ambiguous
```

Comment: Only GCC and ICC consider it ambiguous. MSVC and Clang choose the built-in operator: https://godbolt.org/z/4n4abzxex

Comment: why do you want overload this operator at all?

Comment: I don't want to overload the unary (addressof) operator, but I do want to overload the binary (and) operator.  The problem is that with some compilers overloading the binary operator seems to hide the built-in unary operator

Comment: The unary operator & has one parameter, the binary operator & (bitwise AND), has two parameters.  This is how the compiler differs between the two.

Comment: Anyway included example do not overload unary address of operator.  It overloads binary operator `&` which could be used in context: `instaceOfA & intValue`, so this is bug in gcc it should not report such ambiguity for this code. Here is some test area: https://godbolt.org/z/cjsf68vqd

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/Kfxz1hYoj

Comment: @MarekR That doesn't seem obvious. Even if the overloads are nonviable, they may still be looked up (the operator has the same name), which may be ambiguous, maybe.

Comment: @user17732522 you are right thirst name is resolved (so ambiguity is reported), then number of arguments is matched.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is overload resolution. First function name should be matched and if abutting is found error should be reported. After that matching of arguments is performed. Here is an example with regular function:  https://godbolt.org/z/nYfjdn1Td

As you can see ambiguity is reported for `foo` on all compilers even although both `foo`s have different number of arguments.

Same issue should pop up for `operator&` so more like gcc is right here.

Overload resolution is a complex topic. Usually you do not have to think about it. Here is [nice source](https://youtu.be/b5Kbzgx1w9A) which explains how complex this is.

If you wish to fix problem and have binary operator available for such code, you can do this:

```cpp
struct C : A, B 
{
    using A::operator&;
    using B::operator&;
};
```

This fixes problem with your test on all compilers.

of course ambiguity for `instaceOfC & intValue` remains, but you can resolve it by doping one `using` statement.

https://godbolt.org/z/ds3W4GYcT

Comment: Thanks. Adding the two using directives does indeed solve the problem and enable the built-in unary operator& to be selected.  However, it remains very counter-intuitive that in order to get the wanted function, one has to bring two unwanted functions into C's namespace.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to [unqualified name lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup).

Initially, name lookup begins in the scope of class `C`.  No declarations of `operator&` are found.

Then look up proceeds to [base classes in turn](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.member.lookup#5).  In each of `A` and `B` there is a different declaration with the name `operator&`.

At this point the set of declarations found by name lookup is `A::operator&` and `B::operator&`.  [These are considered ambiguous](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.member.lookup#6.2) at the name lookup stage so overload resolution, where the difference between unary and binary `operator&` would be discovered, is never reached.

[See the example at cppreference for unqualified name look up for more info.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup#Member_function_definition)

If only one of `A` or `B` was inherited then the name lookup set wouldn't be member function name lookup set wouldn't be ambiguous.  It would proceed to overload resolution an correctly deduce unary `operator&`.

[Adding a `using` declaration to the body of class `C`, bring them both into the scope `C::` for name lookup.](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.lookup#unqual-2).

```cpp
struct C : A, B
{
    using A::operator&;
    using B::operator&;
};
```

The scope of `C` is [searched before base classes](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.lookup#unqual-7.1) so the ambiguous step is never reached.

Comment: The member candidates should be looked up by qualified name lookup.

Comment: Only if they are called in a namespace qualified way, e.g. `C::operator&(c)`.  Otherwiseunqualified lookup will begin looking for member functions first.

Comment: Only non-member functions are looked up by unqualified lookup: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/over.match.oper#3.2.sentence-1

Comment: The name lookup fails before overload resolution is reached. https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.lookup#general-1.sentence-5